# Python sorting dictionary according to value? Please review my algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some files to parse. It has time info followed by label and value if it has been modified on that time frame. A very simple example is like:

```
Time 1:00
a 1
b 1
c 2
d 4
Time 2:00
d 2
a 4
c 5
e 7
Time 3:00
c 3
Time 4:00
e 3
a 2
b 5
```

I need to put this into CSV file so I will plot afterwards. The CSV file should look like

```
Time, a, b, c, d, e
1:00, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0
2:00, 4, 1, 5, 4, 7
3:00, 4, 1, 3, 4, 7
4:00, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3
```

Also I need to find the max value of each labels so I can sort my graphs.
Since max values are a:4, b:5, c:5, d:4, e:7, I like to have list such as:
['e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd' ]

What I am doing is going through the log once and reading all labels since I don't know what labels can it be.

Then going through second time in the whole file to parse. My algorithm is simply:

```
for label in labelList:  
    currentValues[label] = 0    
    maxValues[item] = 0

for line in content:
    if endOfCurrentTimeStamp:
        put_current_values_to_CSV()
    else:
        label = line.split()[0]
        value = line.split()[1]
        currentValues[label] = value
        if maxValues[label] < value:
            maxValues[label] = value
```

I got the maxValues of each label in the dictionary. Then what should I do to have a list of sorted from max to min values as said above?

Also let me know if you think an easier way to do the whole thing?

By the way my data is big. I am talking about this input file can easily be hundreds of megabytes with thousands of different labels. So every time I finish a time frame, I put data to CSV.

Regards

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are by nature unsorted so you will have to convert it to a different data type. 
This is probably a little inefficient but you could try the following:

```
to_sort = []
for key in maxValues:
    to_sort.append((maxValues[key], key))
to_sort.sort()
```

A list of tuples will sort based upon the first object if I'm not mistaken

If the tuples won't sort try using itemgetter

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) once you've created your CSV. I'll emulate your file with `StringIO`; you'll feed `read_csv` a real file name:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Time, a, b, c, d, e
1:00, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0
2:00, 4, 1, 5, 4, 7
3:00, 4, 1, 3, 4, 7
4:00, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3"""), index_col=0)
df.apply(max).sort(inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
 a    4
 d    4
 b    5
 c    5
 e    7
dtype: int64
```

Plotting is easy too:

```
df.plot()
```

[image: pandas plot]

Comment: you should avoid the non-vectorized apply and just use `df.max()` instead